# htaccess redirect from /foo/bar/ to foo.php?q=bar

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

as the question states i have managed to do foo.php?q=bar to /foo/bar ,using the below

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^foo\.php$ foo/%1? [R=301,L]
```

how i want the /foo/bar to be redirected to foo.php?q=bar 
**while checking that if**

foo = foo, that is say a file named dosearch exists and gets redirected to

```
dosearch/data
```

now i want to see if

```
/(.*)/(.*)
```

that the first match is dosearch and if it is then do `dosearch.php?q=$2`

EDIT:

This is the new htaccess but it keeps giving me "Too many redirects"

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^dosearch\.php$ dosearch/%1? [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^dosearch/([^/]+)? dosearch.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

Any Help is appretiated guys......

Comment: Isn't `/dosearch/(.*)` what you're looking for ?

Comment: no the first match may some other files which i dont want to be redirected

Comment: Ok, can you provide some input and expected output ? Also do you want to redirect or to rewrite ?

Comment: quietly internally rewrite...like i said bro..../dosearch/data to be checked like /(.*)/(.*) and if first match is 'dosearch' then rewritten to dosearch.php?q=data

Comment: is this possible ?                                                            RewriteCond /(.*)/(.*)  $1=dosearch                                           RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?q=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: I think you just want `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? $1.php?q=$2`

Comment: can u tell me if this will work `RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?q=$2`

Comment: Test it out and you'll know, you may want to use an online tester [1](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) [2](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)

Comment: i tried it out and i keep getting "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: Get ride of that `rewritecond`

Comment: i did now its only RewriteRule ^dosearch/(.*)$ dosearch.php?q=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: i have added the complete htaccess now....could u plz find out the problem...

Comment: yes....edited and added as the htaccess as 'EDIT' in question.

Comment: Use something like [this](http://pastebin.com/ThFjT34K)

Comment: that code works without these 2 lines `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^dosearch\.php$ dosearch/%1? [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: That doesn't make sense, just remove it

Comment: i need that because i want a form query is done it gets done like dosearch.php?q=data and i want that redirected, if u can suggest a better way please do mate.

Answer (score -1):

Hello i think i got this but the following appends no query even though its there....if someone can point out...it would be nice.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /dosearch\.php\?q=(.*)\ HTTP/  
RewriteRule ^dosearch\.php$ dosearch/%1?  [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^dosearch/([^/]+)? dosearch.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```